# Closure Compiler: Import npm package

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I'm wondering, if it is possible use an npm package like sha256 with a project that is compiled with Closure, like https://github.com/angular/closure-demo.

I don't want to use global variables with externs but sth like require('sha256') or import ... from 'sha256';

Is this currently supported?

Wishes,
Manfred

Answer (score 1):

Closure will not compile npm modules that are required by your application, so you would need to use another tool like Browserify in conjunction with Closure. Browserify will traverse your npm dependencies and concatenate them into a single file (example: http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2013/11/backbone-browserify/).

The bundled output of Browserify can then be compiled with Closure like any other JS file. We've used a similar process with gulp to compile Typescript into JS and then further optimize it with Closure.